# Generate multiple comma separated variables

Tags: python

I'm using a function that manipulates values in certain way, based on the other values that I pass to it. Example

```
return foo(a,b)
>>> a_new, b_new
```

or

```
return foo(a,b,c)
>>> a_new, b_new, c_new
```

The function foo is part of a library that cannot be altered.
The variables are generated in a loop a step earlier, and, therefore, are just part of a list. So currently, I'm passing the values manually:

```
return foo(variables[0], variables[1], variables[2])
>>> variables
```

This is quite a drag. How can I code it, so that all the entries in this list are just spelled out and separated by values? So basically a function:

```
def bar(variables):
    ???
    return variables[0], variables[1], ... variables[len(variables)]
```

so I can just

```
return foo(bar(variables)
>>> variables
```

Comment: Have you tried `return ...variables`?

Comment: Sorry, that's Javascript... Have you tried `*variables`?

Comment: FYI, your approach with `foo(bar(variables))` is fundamentally flawed. `bar` could also only return one single value and pass it to `foo`. E.g. it could be rewritten to `baz = bar(variables); foo(baz)`—the exact same thing you already have. `bar` can't generate source code which is then evaluated again, that's not how this works…